# Can I prevent comparison to NULL with overloaded operator==?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a String class that I want to be able to construct or assign with a pointer, but disallow compiling with an explicit std::nullptr assignment:

```
class String {
public:
    String(const char *);
    friend bool operator== (const String &, const char *);
    friend bool operator!= (const String &, const char *);
    // some important things left out
private:
    String(std::nullptr_t);
}
```

The purpose is to give "error: 'operator=' is a private member of 'String'" if I try to write "str = NULL", which helps me identify some bugs in an old codebase.  Obviously, the public constructor should handle the nullptr case as well.  Additionally, it helps me identify some similar issues such as "str = 0", which the compiler will report as ambiguous.

My question is - can I do something similar with binary comparison operators, operator== and operator!=?  I would like the compiler to report an attempted comparison to std::nullptr_t, which is also very common in my codebase.

Comment: I bet you could just do `String(std::nullptr_t) = delete;` and for your operators the same (`friend bool operator==(const String&, std::nullptr_t) = delete`, don't forget the other direction) or something similar

Comment: Have you tried declaring an additional deleted/private operator which takes nullptr_t as the second parameter instead of a C-string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you want to **prohibit** calling a certain function you can append `= delete`, which was introduced in C++11:

```
friend bool operator==(const String&, std::nullptr_t) = delete;
friend bool operator!=(const String&, std::nullptr_t) = delete;
```

Whenever you try to compare your type with `nullptr` you get this compiler error:

```
function "operator==(const String &, std::nullptr_t)" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```